# Flag messages in Outlook with Add-In Express Plugin

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing a plugin for outlook 2007 and higher with Add-In Express in C#.
I want to highlight special mails (e.g. the sender address contains @example.org) in the overview (list) over emails.

With highlight I mean adding an image/logo to the mail or changing the background color or something in that way.

I do not want to use categories for highlighting because they can be changed manually by the user. Only my plugin should be able to highlight special mails.

Is there any possibility to do that with an Add-in Express Plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend asking about Add-in Express specific features on their [forums](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/list.php?FID=5) instead.

As for the Outlook extensibility model, you can use a custom property for your own flags if you don't like [Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863110(v=office.15).aspx). For example, you can use the [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866403(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items which returns the UserProperties collection that represents all the user properties for the Outlook item.

The [PropertyAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863046(v=office.15).aspx) object provides the ability to create, get, set, and delete low-level properties on Outlook items. Use the PropertyAccessor object to get and set item-level properties that are not explicitly exposed in the Outlook object model. To get or set multiple custom properties, use the PropertyAccessor object instead of the UserProperties object for better performance.

Finally, if you need to customize the TableView in the Explorer window you can use the [CurrentView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861617(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Folder or Explorer class. To obtain a View object for the view of the current Explorer, use Explorer.CurrentView instead of the CurrentView property of the current Folder object returned by Explorer.CurrentFolder. Thus, you can add your own defined property into the view.

The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your own view that uses conditional formatting - right click on a header, select View Settings | Conditional Formatting. Note that Outlook Object Model will not let you programmatically access or modify auto formatting settings of a view